# Using a stored procedure for secure login vb.net win forms

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to create a login form that uses a stored procedure to check user exists and access the system vb.net using VS2015 & SQL Server 2012.

I have created the following table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[User]
(
    UserID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    LoginName NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    PasswordHash BINARY(64) NOT NULL,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(40) NULL,
    LastName NVARCHAR(40) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_User_UserID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserID ASC)
)
```

and run the following to update the table

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[User] ADD Salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.uspAddUser
    @pLogin NVARCHAR(50), 
    @pPassword NVARCHAR(50),
    @pFirstName NVARCHAR(40) = NULL, 
    @pLastName NVARCHAR(40) = NULL,
    @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @salt UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID()
    BEGIN TRY

        INSERT INTO dbo.[User] (LoginName, PasswordHash, Salt, FirstName, LastName)
        VALUES(@pLogin, HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pPassword+CAST(@salt AS NVARCHAR(36))), @salt, @pFirstName, @pLastName)

       SET @responseMessage='Success'

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @responseMessage=ERROR_MESSAGE() 
    END CATCH

END
```

all based from this source https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4037/storing-passwords-in-a-secure-way-in-a-sql-server-database/

I have created a simple form with user and password box submit button I am using the following code on the submit button

```
 Private Sub RadButtonSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadButtonSubmit.Click
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter()
        Try
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.Connection)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("uspLogin", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pLoginName", RadTextBoxUser.Text.Trim())
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pPassword", RadTextBoxPass.Text.Trim())
            adp.SelectCommand = cmd
            adp.Fill(dt)
            cmd.Dispose()
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                RadLabelMessage.Text = "Login Successfull"
                'Or in show messagebox using  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Login Successfull');", true);
                'Or write using Response.Write("Login Successfull");
                'Or redirect using Response.Redirect("Mypanel.aspx");
            Else
                RadLabelMessage.Text = "Wrong Username/Password"
                'Or show in messagebox usingScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Wrong Username/Password');", true);
                'Or write using Response.Write("Wrong Username/Password"); 
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Message", "alert('Oops!! following error occured : " & ex.Message.ToString() & "');", True)
            ' Response.Write("Oops!! following error occured: " +ex.Message.ToString());           
        Finally
            dt.Clear()
            dt.Dispose()
            adp.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

When I enter username and password it always displays "Wrong Username/Password"

I added the user using

```
DECLARE @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250)

EXEC dbo.uspAddUser
          @pLogin = N'Admin',
          @pPassword = N'123',
          @pFirstName = N'Admin',
          @pLastName = N'Administrator',
          @responseMessage=@responseMessage OUTPUT

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[User]
```

this is the stored procedure for the login

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspLogin
    @pLoginName NVARCHAR(254),
    @pPassword NVARCHAR(50),
    @responseMessage NVARCHAR(250)='' OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @userID INT

    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 UserID FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE LoginName=@pLoginName)
    BEGIN
        SET @userID=(SELECT UserID FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE LoginName=@pLoginName AND PasswordHash=HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @pPassword+CAST(Salt AS NVARCHAR(36))))

       IF(@userID IS NULL)
           SET @responseMessage='Incorrect password'
       ELSE 
           SET @responseMessage='User successfully logged in'
    END
    ELSE
       SET @responseMessage='Invalid login'

END
```

I can see the user exists in my db any suggestions on how I can fix this

Thanks
M

I recreated the login form using the following code

```
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Public Class Login
    Private FirstNameValid As Boolean 'Is Name  Valid?
    Private LastNameValid As Boolean 'Is Surname Valid?
    Private XUserNameValid As Boolean
    Private UserPassValid As Boolean
    Private EmailValid As Boolean 'Is Email Valid?

    Private Sub FirstName_Leave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles FirstName.Leave
        If FirstName.Text = "" Then ErrorLabel.Text = "Please Enter Your First Name!"
        'If Not A Matching Format Entered
        If Not Regex.Match(FirstName.Text, "^[a-z]*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success Then 'Only Letters

            ErrorLabel.Text = "Please Enter Alphabetic Characters Only!" 'Inform User

            FirstName.Focus() 'Return Focus
            FirstName.Clear() 'Clear TextBox

            FirstNameValid = False 'Boolean = False
        Else

            FirstNameValid = True 'Everything Fine
            ErrorLabel.Text = ""
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub LastName_Leave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LastName.Leave

        'Create A Pattern For Surname
        Dim strSurname As String = "^[a-zA-Z\s]+$"

        Dim reSurname As New Regex(strSurname) 'Attach Pattern To Surname Textbox

        'Not A Match
        If Not reSurname.IsMatch(LastName.Text) Then

            ErrorLabel.Text = "Please Enter Alphabetic Characters Only!"

            LastName.Focus()

            LastName.Clear()

            LastNameValid = False

        Else

            LastNameValid = True
            ErrorLabel.Text = ""

        End If

    End Sub
    Private Sub UserPass_Leave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles UserPass.Leave
        If UserPass.Text = "" Then ErrorLabel.Text = "Please Enter Your Password!"
        If UserPass.Text.Length < "8" Then

            ErrorLabel.Text = "Password must be 8 Charecters!"
            UserPass.Focus()

            UserPass.Clear()

            UserPassValid = False

        Else

            UserPassValid = True
            ErrorLabel.Text = ""

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ValidateEmail()

        'Set Up Reg Exp Pattern To Allow Most Characters, And No Special Characters
        Dim reEmail As Regex = New Regex("([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\." +
        ")|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase _
        Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant _
        Or RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace _
        Or RegexOptions.Compiled
        )

        Dim blnPossibleMatch As Boolean = reEmail.IsMatch(UserEmail.Text)

        If blnPossibleMatch Then

            'Check If Entered Email Is In Correct Format
            If Not UserEmail.Text.Equals(reEmail.Match(UserEmail.Text).ToString) Then

                ErrorLabel.Text = "Invalid Email Address!"

            Else

                EmailValid = True 'Email is Perfect

            End If

        Else 'Not A Match To Pattern

            EmailValid = False 'Set Boolean Variable To False

            ErrorLabel.Text = "Invalid Email Address!" 'Inform User

            UserEmail.Clear() 'Clear Textbox

            UserEmail.Focus() 'Set Focus To TextBox

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtEmail_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles UserEmail.LostFocus
        If UserEmail.Text = "" Then ErrorLabel.Text = "Invalid Email Address!"
        ValidateEmail() 'Check Email Validity

    End Sub
    'The maximum number of times the user can try to login.
    Private Const MAX_ATTEMPT_COUNT As Integer = 3

    'The number of times the user has tried to login.
    Private attemptCount As Integer = 0


    Private Sub Login_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RadPanel1.Show()
        RadPanel2.Hide()
        RadLabel7.Text = "Register"

        TextBoxUserName.Focus()
        Dim splash As SplashScreen1 = CType(My.Application.SplashScreen, SplashScreen1)
        Dim MadeUpSteps() As String = {"Initializing...", "Loading ports...", "Checking Connection...", "Please wait...", "Connecting..."}

        For i As Integer = 0 To MadeUpSteps.Length - 1
            splash.UpdateProgress(MadeUpSteps(i), CInt((i + 1) / MadeUpSteps.Length * 100))
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500)
        Next
        Dim tcpc As New TcpClient()
        Try
            tcpc.Connect("cloud01.smarthosting.co.uk", 80)
            Return
        Catch


            If MessageBox.Show("Sorry No connection is available try again later.",
                   "Connection Error",
                   MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                   MessageBoxIcon.Error) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

                Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
                Me.Close()

            End If

        End Try
    End Sub
    Dim adminLogin As Boolean


    Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click


        Dim x As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider()
        Dim bs As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TextBoxPassword.Text)
        bs = x.ComputeHash(bs)
        Dim s As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        For Each b As Byte In bs
            s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower())
        Next
        TextBoxPassword.Text = s.ToString()
        Dim pass = TextBoxPassword.Text

        If Me.ValidateCredentials Then
            Dim Obj As New Main
            adminLogin = False
            My.Forms.Main.RadTextBox1.Text = adminLogin
            Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK



        ElseIf Me.ValidateCredentials1 Then
            Dim Obj As New Main
            adminLogin = True
            My.Forms.Main.RadTextBox1.Text = adminLogin
            Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK


        Else
            Me.attemptCount += 1

            Dim message As String

            If Me.attemptCount = MAX_ATTEMPT_COUNT Then
                message = "The maximum number of failed logins has been reached." &
                          Environment.NewLine &
                          "The application will now exit."
                Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort
            Else
                message = "The provided credentials are incorrect." &
                          Environment.NewLine &
                          "Please try again."
                Me.TextBoxPassword.Clear()
                Me.TextBoxUserName.SelectAll()
                Me.TextBoxUserName.Select()
            End If

            MessageBox.Show(message,
                            "Login Failed",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Cancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cancel.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit without logging in?",
                           "Confirm Exit",
                           MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                           MessageBoxIcon.None) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function ValidateCredentials() As Boolean
        Dim result As Boolean


        result = Me.ValidateCredentialsByTableAdapter()

        Return result
    End Function

    Private Function ValidateCredentialsByTableAdapter() As Boolean
        Using adapter As New System3DataSetTableAdapters.UserTableAdapter
            Return adapter.ScalarQuery(Me.TextBoxUserName.Text.Trim(),
                                                             Me.TextBoxPassword.Text).Value > 0
        End Using
    End Function
    Private Function ValidateCredentials1() As Boolean
        Dim result As Boolean


        result = Me.ValidateCredentialsByTableAdapter1()

        Return result
    End Function

    Private Function ValidateCredentialsByTableAdapter1() As Boolean
        Using adapter As New System3DataSetTableAdapters.Admin8TableAdapter
            Return adapter.ScalarQuery(Me.TextBoxUserName.Text.Trim(),
                                                             Me.TextBoxPassword.Text).Value > 0
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Sub RadLabel7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadLabel7.Click
        If RadPanel1.Visible = True Then
            RadLabel7.Text = "Login"
            RadPanel2.Show()
            RadPanel1.Hide()


        ElseIf RadPanel2.Visible = True Then
            RadLabel7.Text = "Register"
            RadPanel1.Show()
            RadPanel2.Hide()

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub RadButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadButton1.Click
        Dim x As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512CryptoServiceProvider()
        Dim bs As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(UserPass.Text)
        bs = x.ComputeHash(bs)
        Dim s As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        For Each b As Byte In bs
            s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower())
        Next
        UserPass.Text = s.ToString()
        Dim pass = UserPass.Text
        Dim myConnection As New System.Data.ConnectionState
        Dim mySqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Users", myConnection)
        Dim myDataSet As New DataSet()
        Dim myDataRow As DataRow

        ' Create command builder. This line automatically generates the update commands for you, so you don't 
        ' have to provide or create your own.
        Dim mySqlCommandBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter)

        ' Set the MissingSchemaAction property to AddWithKey because Fill will not cause primary
        ' key & unique key information to be retrieved unless AddWithKey is specified.
        mySqlDataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey

        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Users")

        myDataRow = myDataSet.Tables("Users").NewRow()
        myDataRow("ID") = "NewID"
        myDataRow("xFirstName") = FirstName.Text
        myDataRow("xLastName") = LastName.Text
        myDataRow("xEmail") = UserEmail.Text
        myDataRow("UserPass") = pass

        myDataSet.Tables("Users").Rows.Add(myDataRow)
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class PasswordHash

    Public Const SALT_BYTE_SIZE As Integer = 24
    Public Const HASH_BYTE_SIZE As Integer = 24
    Public Const PBKDF2_ITERATIONS As Integer = 1000

    Public Const ITERATION_INDEX As Integer = 0
    Public Const SALT_INDEX As Integer = 1
    Public Const PBKDF2_INDEX As Integer = 2


    Public Shared Function CreateHash(password As String) As String
        ' Generate a random salt
        Dim csprng As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()
        Dim salt As Byte() = New Byte(SALT_BYTE_SIZE - 1) {}
        csprng.GetBytes(salt)

        ' Hash the password and encode the parameters
        Dim hash As Byte() = PBKDF2(password, salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, HASH_BYTE_SIZE)
        Return PBKDF2_ITERATIONS + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(salt) + ":" + Convert.ToBase64String(hash)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Validates a password given a hash of the correct one.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="password">The password to check.</param>
    ''' <param name="correctHash">A hash of the correct password.</param>
    ''' <returns>True if the password is correct. False otherwise.</returns>
    Public Shared Function ValidatePassword(password As String, correctHash As String) As Boolean
        ' Extract the parameters from the hash
        Dim delimiter As Char() = {":"c}
        Dim split As String() = correctHash.Split(delimiter)
        Dim iterations As Integer = Int32.Parse(split(ITERATION_INDEX))
        Dim salt As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(split(SALT_INDEX))
        Dim hash As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(split(PBKDF2_INDEX))

        Dim testHash As Byte() = PBKDF2(password, salt, iterations, hash.Length)
        Return SlowEquals(hash, testHash)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Compares two byte arrays in length-constant time. This comparison
    ''' method is used so that password hashes cannot be extracted from
    ''' on-line systems using a timing attack and then attacked off-line.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="a">The first byte array.</param>
    ''' <param name="b">The second byte array.</param>
    ''' <returns>True if both byte arrays are equal. False otherwise.</returns>
    Private Shared Function SlowEquals(a As Byte(), b As Byte()) As Boolean
        Dim diff As UInteger = CUInt(a.Length) Xor CUInt(b.Length)
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While i < a.Length AndAlso i < b.Length
            diff = diff Or CUInt(a(i) Xor b(i))
            i += 1
        End While
        Return diff = 0
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Computes the PBKDF2-SHA1 hash of a password.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="password">The password to hash.</param>
    ''' <param name="salt">The salt.</param>
    ''' <param name="iterations">The PBKDF2 iteration count.</param>
    ''' <param name="outputBytes">The length of the hash to generate, in bytes.</param>
    ''' <returns>A hash of the password.</returns>
    Private Shared Function PBKDF2(password As String, salt As Byte(), iterations As Integer, outputBytes As Integer) As Byte()
        Dim pbkdf2__1 As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt)
        pbkdf2__1.IterationCount = iterations
        Return pbkdf2__1.GetBytes(outputBytes)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: I think you should edit your question to add the SQL source code for your uspLogin stored procedure, even if it's identical to the link you provided (which we don't know that it is).

Answer (score 0):

The uspLogin stored procedure returns its result as a @responseMessage output parameter, not as a result set. So your .NET code for login should not use a DataTable to get the result; instead it should define a @responseMessage output parameter.

Use code like this:

```
Dim resultParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@responseMessage", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250)
resultParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Dim res = resultParam.Value.ToString()
```